# Objective-C some special char uncontrollably changing

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a string that include some special char (like é,â,î,ı etc.), When I use substring on this string. I encounter inconsistent results. Some special char change uncontrollably

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are assuming that these are all *characters*:

```
[newword substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,1)];    
[newword substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1,1)];
[newword substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(2,1)];    
[newword substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(3,1)];
// and so on...
```

In other words, you believe that:

- A `location` always falls at the start of a character.
- A character always has `length` 1.

Both assumptions are wrong. Please read the Characters and Grapheme Clusters chapter of Apple's *String Programming Guide* ([here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/stringsClusters.html)).

Your `é` happens to have length 2, because it is a base letter `e` followed by a *combining* diacritical accent. If you want it to have length 1, you need to *normalize* the string before you use it. Call [`precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1412645-precomposedstringwithcanonicalma?language=objc) and use the resulting string.

Example and proof (in Swift, but it won't matter, as I use NSString throughout):

```
let s = "é,â,î,ı" as NSString
let c = s.substring(with: NSRange(location: 0, length: 1)) // e
let s2 = s.precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping as NSString
let c2 = s2.substring(with: NSRange(location: 0, length: 1)) // é
```

Comment: I should also point out, in the name of sanity, that if you used Swift instead of Objective-C you wouldn't have this problem, because Swift walks the string for you and decomposes it into _actual_ characters.

Comment: Since there are many composed character sequences that have no corresponding single precomposed character, it's worth also pointing out that `NSString` has methods `rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex:`, `rangeOfComposedCharacterSequencesForRange:`, and `enumerateSubstringsInRange:options:usingBlock:` (with the `NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences` option) for dividing a string between composed character sequence boundaries.

Comment: @robmayoff Very good point; my answer was based directly on the particular string the OP gave, but of course there are simple-minded assumptions built into it for that very reason.

Answer (score 2):

You're treating a unicode string like a sequence of bytes. Unicode codepoints, aside from low UTF8 can be multi-byte so you are changing the text style by stripping out parts responsible for the accent above the letter like this part: https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0301

UTF8 is variable width so by treating it as raw bytes you may get weird results, I would suggest using something that is more aware of unicode like ICU ([International Components for Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Components_for_Unicode)).

Now imagine you have a two byte sequence like this (this may not be 100% accurate but it illustrates my point):

```
0x056 0x000
  e    NUL
```

Now you have a UTF8 string with 1 codepoint and a null terminator. Now say you want to add an accent to that `e`. How would you do that? You could use a special unicode codepoint to modify the `e` so now the string is:

```
0x056 0x0CC 0x810 0x000
  e     U+0301     NUL
```

Where `U+0301` is 2 a byte control character (Combining Acute Accent) and makes the `e` accented.

---

**Edit:** The answer assumes UTF8 encoding which is likely a bad assumption but I think the answer, whether UTF8 or UTF16, or any other type of encoding with control characters, illustrates why you may have mysterious dissapearing accents. While this may be UTF16, for the sake of simplicity let's pretend we live in a world where life is just slightly better because everyone only uses UTF8 and UTF16 doesn't exist.

---

To address the comment (this is less to do with the question but is some fun trivia) and for some fun detils about NS/CF/Swift runtimes and bridging and constant CF strings and other fun stuff like that: The representation of the actual string in memory is **implementation defined** and can vary (even for constant strings, trust me, I know, I fixed the ELF implementation of them in Clang for CoreFoundation a few days ago). Anyway, here's some code:

```
CF_INLINE CFStringEncoding __CFStringGetSystemEncoding(void) {
    if (__CFDefaultSystemEncoding == kCFStringEncodingInvalidId) (void)CFStringGetSystemEncoding();
    return __CFDefaultSystemEncoding;
}

CFStringEncoding CFStringFileSystemEncoding(void) {
    if (__CFDefaultFileSystemEncoding == kCFStringEncodingInvalidId) {
#if DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_MACOSX || DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_EMBEDDED || DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_EMBEDDED_MINI || DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_WINDOWS
        __CFDefaultFileSystemEncoding = kCFStringEncodingUTF8;
#else
        __CFDefaultFileSystemEncoding = CFStringGetSystemEncoding();
#endif
    }
    return __CFDefaultFileSystemEncoding;
}
```

Throughout CoreFoundation/Foundation/SwiftFoundation (Yes you never know what sort of NSString is actually the one you're holding, they usually pretend to be the same thing but under the hood depending on how you got the object you may be holding onto one of the three variations of it).

This is why code like this exists, because NS/CF(Constant)/Swift strings have implementation defined internal representation.

```
if (((encoding & 0x0FFF) == kCFStringEncodingUnicode) && ((encoding == kCFStringEncodingUnicode) || ((encoding > kCFStringEncodingUTF8) && (encoding <= kCFStringEncodingUTF32LE)))) {
```

If you want consistent behavior you have to encode the string using a specific **fixed** encoding instead of relying on the internal representation.

Comment: Almost right, `NSString` is stored as a sequence of UTF-16 code points, not UTF-8, and all indexes, ranges, counts etc. refer to these code points (see "String Objects" in the [`NSString` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring?language=objc)). And indeed to get the behaviour the OP reports the é must be represented by the composed pair, 0x65 & 0x301.

Comment: `NSString` stores the internal representation as UTF8 or UTF16 depending on the case. It's an implementation detail, the documentation doesn't concern you with that. Also this is likely an `_NSCFString` object.

Comment: Don't you think the OP's problem might have more to do with normalization than UTF8? The OP is not looking at _bytes_ at all. This answer, while fascinating, has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: I think whether it's UTF16 or UTF8, he's cutting off a control byte which results in said behavior.

Comment: OK, I concede that maybe I should have written "presents itself as though stored as" rather than simply "stored as" ;-) The key issue is that even after normalisation a single character may require 2 UTF-16 code units, so there is no 1-1 mapping from string to character indices as @matt has also pointed out.